# Computing total_seconds in Python for datetime module with true division enabled

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to do some computations on date, I have a `timedelta` object, and I want to get the number of seconds. It seems like `dt.total_seconds()` does exactly what I need but unfortunately it was introduced in Python 2.7 and I'm stuck with an older version.

If I read [the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds), it states the following:

> Return the total number of seconds contained in the duration. Equivalent to (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6 computed **with true division enabled**.

And after looking at the source of the `datetime` module (in C), I see something like this:

```
total_seconds = PyNumber_TrueDivide(total_microseconds, one_million);
```

So while the computation of `total_seconds()` seems trivial, that leaves me wondering what this **true division** actually means. I couldn't find any info on the topic. What happens if I just use regular division, why do we need this true division and what does it do? Can I just write `total_seconds()` in Python with the equivalent given in the doc?

Comment: +1 Great question! The docs should probably be clearer on this point.

Comment: @JohnMachin This doesn't change the fact that the doc is unclear on this topic. Thanks for your constructive comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With true division, `1 / 2` would result in `0.5`.  The default behavior in Python 2.x is to use integer division, where `1 / 2` would result in `0`.  Here is the explanation from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

> Plain or long integer division yields an integer of the same type; the result is that of mathematical division with the ‘floor’ function applied to the result.

To enable true division on Python 2.2 or higher (not necessary on  Python 3.x), you can use the following:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Alternatively, you can just make one of the arguments a float to get the same behavior:

```
(td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10.0**6
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do this, when you're using numbers in the code anyway is to use a float on the first division.

If you use 10.0**6, your result will be a float, which means that all further numbers in the formula will be float as well, which leads to "true division".